# Local plugin enabling chinese

Tags: moodle

I am new to moodle.I have created a local plugin and inside the lang folder created a folder zh_cn for chinese. Inside zh_cn folder i placed php file local_*pluginname* and put chinese strings.But it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the Simplified Chinese language pack installed?

Go to site admin -> language -> language packs and choose Simplified Chinese (zh_cn)

If you have that installed and the plugin is showing [stringid] then the the language cache needs updating.

On your development machine it will be easier if you add this to your config.php

```
$CFG->langstringcache = false;
```

On the production site go to site admin -> language -> language settings, uncheck "Cache all language strings", save, then check it again and save. This will update the language cache.

Comment: It is working. Thanks for the reply and guidance. I had hope from you that you would reply. Sorry for placing this comment late ,as I am in India and was working late yesterday night. I have a doubt regarding lang folder files, but  i will post it as a separate question as give you the link here so that you can answer there...